Blazor InputSelect error: "TypeError: o.parentNode is null" when modifying value
I have the following Blazor InputSelect
<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="MdfAddressbook.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole">
    <option value="@ClsUsersRoles.OBSERVER">@Localizer[LocalTranslations.GnrcText_Observer]</option>
    <option value="@ClsUsersRoles.SUBCONTRACTOR">@Localizer[LocalTranslations.GnrcText_Subcontractor]</option>
</InputSelect>

which translates correctly to the following HTML:
<select name="MdfAddressbook.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole" class="form-select modified valid" _bl_f951b65f-1ea1-4713-8094-b4a2cb355ca0="">
    <option value="OBSERVER">Observer</option>
    <!--!-->
    <option value="SUBCONTRACTOR">Subcontractor</option>
</select>

The Poperty is backed up by this (NHibernate) field:
private String _FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole = ClsUsersRoles.UNKNOWN;
public virtual String FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole
{
    get { return _FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole; }
    set { _FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole = value; }
}


and shows up with the correct value when I open the Modal containing it.
Everything works correctly when MdfAddressbook is a new Object, however, when editing an existing MdfAddressbook Object, as soon as I select a different value using my mouse (at the selection instant) i get the following errors:
[2024-10-28T17:26:03.019Z] Error: There was an error applying batch 32. blazor.web.js:1:40375
    log https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    processBatch https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startConnection https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _invokeClientMethod https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _processIncomingData https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    onreceive https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    onmessage https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    (Asinc.: EventHandlerNonNull)
    connect https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    connect https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startTransport https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _createTransport https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startInternal https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    start https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startInternal https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startWithStateTransitions https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    start https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startConnection https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startCore https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    start https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    or https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    nr https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startCircutIfNotStarted https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    resolveRendererIdForDescriptor https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    determinePendingOperation https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    refreshRootComponents https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    (Asinc.: setTimeout handler)
    rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    onDocumentUpdated https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    Ki https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    (Asinc.: EventListener.handleEvent)
    Ji https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    <anonima> https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    <anonima> https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
[2024-10-28T17:26:03.092Z] Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: o.parentNode is null)

 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: o.parentNode is null

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- blazor.web.js:1:40375
    log https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    unhandledError https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startConnection https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _invokeClientMethod https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _processIncomingData https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    onreceive https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    onmessage https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    (Asinc.: EventHandlerNonNull)
    connect https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    connect https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startTransport https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _createTransport https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startInternal https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    start https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startInternal https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    _startWithStateTransitions https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    start https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startConnection https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startCore https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    start https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    or https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    nr https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    startCircutIfNotStarted https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    resolveRendererIdForDescriptor https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    determinePendingOperation https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    refreshRootComponents https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    (Asinc.: setTimeout handler)
    rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    onDocumentUpdated https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    Ki https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    (Asinc.: EventListener.handleEvent)
    Ji https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    <anonima> https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1
    <anonima> https://localhost:7185/_framework/blazor.web.js:1

I am at a los beacuse the error seems to be coming from the internals of blazor

Hi @Guido De Vecchi, could you pls share your whole razor component code? TypeError: o.parentNode is null—often happens when the component attempts to access the DOM, but the required elements aren’t available, often due to timing issues in Blazor rendering or handling.

@Rena thanks for investing some of your time in my problem. I was able to find a solution, the problem was in a completly different Component on the same page that was referencing the same variable I was modifying in the InputSelect

So, here I am, 2 days later, having understood that the problem was entirely somewhere else. Solved here
In the same page, I have a Grid Component, where one of the GridColumns was defined as:
<GridColumn TItem="AnaAddressBooks" Context="chContext" HeaderText="@Localizer[LocalTranslations.Customers_AddressbookDefaultRole_Lbl]">
    @if (chContext.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole.Equals(ClsUsersRoles.OBSERVER)) {
        <i class="fa-solid fa-binoculars"></i>
    }
    @if (chContext.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole.Equals(ClsUsersRoles.SUBCONTRACTOR)) {
        <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench"></i>
    }
</GridColumn>

After commenting it out, I discovered that the error was disappearing.
Turns out, if I transformed the GridColumn like this:
<GridColumn TItem="AnaAddressBooks" Context="chContext" HeaderText="@Localizer[LocalTranslations.Customers_AddressbookDefaultRole_Lbl]" >
    @if (chContext.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole.Equals(ClsUsersRoles.OBSERVER)) {
        <div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-binoculars"></i>
        </div>
    }
    @if (chContext.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole.Equals(ClsUsersRoles.SUBCONTRACTOR)) {
        <div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench"></i>
        </div>
    }
</GridColumn>

,embedding the two FontAwesome icons each in a div element, the error was gone.
Note that embedding the entire @if in a div, like this:
<GridColumn TItem="AnaAddressBooks" Context="chContext" HeaderText="@Localizer[LocalTranslations.Customers_AddressbookDefaultRole_Lbl]">
    <div>
        @if (chContext.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole.Equals(ClsUsersRoles.OBSERVER))     {
            <i class="fa-solid fa-binoculars"></i>
        }
        @if (chContext.FK_Cls_DefaultUserRole.Equals(ClsUsersRoles.SUBCONTRACTOR)) {
            <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench"></i>
        }
    </div>
</GridColumn>

still wouldn't work and would give the same error.
Edit:
In the end I was partially inspired by this StackOverflow thread that featured a similar error
